# I change/load the content in child Select Box, depending on the parent Select Box options using html

Tags: html, css, select, menu

I am using below code and I don't know how make it change/load the content in child Select Box, depending on the parent Select Box options

```
<div class="middle_row row_white search_row">

    <div class="container">
        <form action="#" class="search_form advsearch_hide clearfix">
            <div class="row field_select">
                <label class="label_title">Select Product:</label>
                <select name="car_maker" class="select_styled">
                    <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
                    <option value="1">Automatic Filling Lines</option>
                    <option value="2">Packaging Machines for Food industries &amp; Bakaries</option>
                    <option value="3">Automatic Vertical Packaging Machines</option>
                    <option value="4">Vacuum Machines</option>
                    <option value="5">Gluing Machines</option>
                    <option value="6">Automatic Shrink Wrapping</option>
                    <option value="7">Automatic Cup Filling &amp; Sealing Machines</option>
                    <option value="8">Banding Machines</option>
                    <option value="9">Packaging Materials</option>                    
                      </select>
            </div>

            <div class="row field_select">
                <label class="label_title">Select Category:</label>
                <select class="select_styled" name="car_model">
                    <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
                    <option value="1">Category1</option>
                    <option value="2">Category2</option>
                    <option value="3">Category3</option>
                    <option value="4">Category4</option>
                    <option value="5">Category5</option>
                    <option value="6">Category6</option>                                                                                       
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="row field_select">
                <label class="label_title">Select Model:</label>
                <select class="select_styled" name="car_year">
                    <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
                    <option value="1">Model1</option>
                    <option value="2">Model2</option>
                    <option value="3">Model3</option>
                    <option value="4">Model4</option>
                    <option value="5">Model5</option>
                    <option value="6">Model6</option>                                                
                </select>
            </div>
```

And I don't know how to make it change/load the content in child Select Box, depending on the parent Select Box options? Could you please help me...

Comment: You're going to need to write some JavaScript to make this happen. Essentially you need to find out how to do two things: Respond to the `change` event of one `select` element, and set the `option` elements in another `select` element. Once you have each one working, you can logically combine them. You *might* need to do a third thing, depending on where you *get* your child `select` options. If they're server-side, you'd need to use AJAX to get them. If there aren't too many of them, however, then you can store them in the JavaScript code and use them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row field_select">
        <label class="label_title">Select Product:</label>
        <select id="car_maker" class="select_styled" onchange="updateChild()">
            <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
            <option value="1">Automatic Filling Lines</option>
            <option value="2">Packaging Machines for Food industries &amp; Bakaries</option>
            <option value="3">Automatic Vertical Packaging Machines</option>
            <option value="4">Vacuum Machines</option>
            <option value="5">Gluing Machines</option>
            <option value="6">Automatic Shrink Wrapping</option>                  
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row field_select">
        <label class="label_title">Select Category:</label>
        <select class="select_styled" id="car_model" onchange="updateSubChild()">
            <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
            <option value="1">Category1</option>
            <option value="2">Category2</option>
            <option value="3">Category3</option>
            <option value="4">Category4</option>
            <option value="5">Category5</option>
            <option value="6">Category6</option>                                                                                       
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row field_select">
        <label class="label_title">Select Model:</label>
        <select class="select_styled" id="car_year">
            <option value="0" class="default">- SELECT -</option>
            <option value="1">Model1</option>
            <option value="2">Model2</option>
            <option value="3">Model3</option>
            <option value="4">Model4</option>
            <option value="5">Model5</option>
            <option value="6">Model6</option>                                                
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateChild()
{
    document.getElementById('car_model').value = document.getElementById('car_maker').value;
            document.getElementById('car_year').value = document.getElementById('car_maker').value;
}
</script>
```

Hope this is answer to your question as far as i understood.

Comment: if that's what you were looking let me know.

Comment: Now in above code, When you Select product, it will change Category and Model respectively to Select product.

Comment: yes this answer very useful, but I still have debugs instead of I am not a professional. So, Can you make it and I can pay on this work? If that could you please give me your email to can to handle that with you?

Comment: Yes bro! Surely we are even. you can check my profile for email. And what you are attempting to do is usually done with AJAX not like the way you intend. Whatever, plz provide complete details with scenrio you are facing so i can understand better and make you understand even better.

Comment: Really you are a very helpful and friendly man.. I checked your profile but I didn't find your email! Please send it to me here?

Answer (score 0):

update your parent with onchange event calling our created function updateChild() in javascript.

```
<select class="select_styled" name="car_model" onchange="updateChild()">
```

write this function in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateChild()
{
  document.getElementsByName('car_year').value = document.getElementsByName('car_model').value;
}
</script>
```

This function just simply take value from parent and sets in child accordingly to parent's value and as we have called it onchange event so it executes on change of element.

Comment: Really thanks for your reply, but I am a beginner so, Could you please give me more instructions :) I added your answer to the code but then .. what can I do?

Comment: Really I appreciated :) I have on this template many javascript files! Which one I should add this code on?

Comment: that doesn't matter as long as js file is linked with your html document. You can write this code in any js file which is linked.

Comment: I did as you answered me, but I don't know how to handle parent with the child

Comment: You mean changing parent elements on change of child element?

Comment: Please read my code again, because the parent select is select_product

Comment: Other wise Could you please help me on this link : http://jsfiddle.net/RWUdb/113/

Comment: Ameen plz be more specific so i can answer better. I dont get your point.

Comment: I saw your fiddle but plz tell me what is your goal in deeper explanation. so i can make you understand

Comment: my target is to when I select X1 Product then load/update child Y1 Category then load/update child Z1 Model

Comment: Are you understand me? Again I mean I want to : when select product 1 .. It showing me Category 1 list .. then it showing me Model 1 list    and If I select Product 1 > category 2 list > model 2 list